# TruncatedChunkException when querying my SPARQL endpoint with Jena

Tags: sparql, jena

I'm executing a query against my SPARQL endpoint and getting a strange error (see below). But if I add a pretty low LIMIT in the number of results my query returns a result as expected. As a test I queried DBpedia and had no issues even for retrieving millions of results. I suspect that it has something to do with some of the data that is being returned from my endpoint is causing the issue. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(sparqlEndpoint,
            sparqlQuery);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.atlas.AtlasException:
>   org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException: Truncated chunk ( expected
>   size: 4096; actual size: 3151)

Answer (score 1):

The other end is sending broken data (at the HTTP level).
Check the service at sparqlEndpoint.